# Why Natbib is moving the "see" word at the end of the in-text citation?

Tags: natbib

I am trying to include the word "*see*" in my references using Natabib but the example below always end up moving the word "*see*" at the end of the in-text citation. Here is the output: "This is how you cite a reference (Rose and Harrison, 2010; Wright, 1997, see)".
However, i would like the output to be something like: "This is how you cite a reference (see Rose and Harrison, 2010; Wright, 1997)".

Can someone help please?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}  %

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

This is how you cite a reference \citep[see]{rose_social_2010,wright_class_1997}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

Here are the references:

```
    @book{rose_social_2010,
    address = {London ; New York},
    series = {Routledge/{ESA} studies in {European} societies},
    title = {Social class in {Europe}: an introduction to the {European} {Socio}-economic {Classification}},
    isbn = {978-0-415-45801-6 978-0-203-93058-8},
    shorttitle = {Social class in {Europe}},
    number = {10},
    publisher = {Routledge},
    editor = {Rose, David and Harrison, Eric},
    year = {2010},
    keywords = {Classification, Economic conditions Classification, Europe, Europeans, Social classes, Social conditions Classification, Social stratification},
}

@book{wright_class_1997,
    address = {Cambridge},
    series = {Studies in {Marxism} and social theory},
    title = {Class counts: comparative studies in class analysis},
    isbn = {978-0-521-55387-2 978-0-521-55646-0},
    shorttitle = {Class counts},
    publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
    author = {Wright, Erik Olin},
    year = {1997},
    keywords = {Social classes, Social mobility, Class consciousness},}
```

Comment: Try `\cjte[see][]{foo}`.

Comment: As Oleg mentions natbib citations has two optional arguments, if called with just one, it assumes it to be a `post note`, if called with two optional the first is used as the `pre note` and the latter as the `post note`. This is all listed in the nice manual for `natbib`.